# Does a Nonhomogeneous linear differential equation imply itself that it is not linear?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am troubled by the fact that we call a nonhomogeneous differential equation of the form :

$a_0(x)y+a_1(x)y'+a_2(x)y''+...+a_n(x)y^{(n)}=b(x)$, where $b(x)$ is nonzero. Linear.

From what I know, being homogeneous or having the homogeneity property for differential equations is to satisfy the rule : $Lay(x)=aLy(x)$, therefore if the differential equation is not homogeneous, then it cannot satisfy the homogeneity property: $Lay(x)=aLy(x)$.

I also know though that for a differential equation to be linear, it must both satisfy the additive property and homogeneity property, but since the nonhomogeneous differential equation above doesn't satisfy the homogeneous property, then it must be nonlinear right ?

Answer (score 0):

We call the non-homogeneous DE you wrote out linear because the operator that acts on $y$ is linear:
$$L=a_0(x)+a_1(x)D+a_2(x)D^2+\cdots+a_n(x)D^n,$$
where $D=d/dx$ is the derivative operator. That is, you can write the DE as $Ly=b(x).$ $L$ is linear in the true sense. It's no different from what we call a linear operator in linear algebra if we're solving the matrix equation $Ax=b.$ It's still a linear equation, despite being non-homogeneous, because the operator $A$ is linear.

We do have a word, by the way, for an equation like $y=mx+b,$ which is the word *affine*.

Comment: I understand that the linear operator that acts upon $y(x)$ is linear, it's literally in the name, but I don't understand why it makes the differential equation linear. For instance consider the differential equation $Ly(x) = b(x)$, if this differential equation is linear (by the rules of linearity), then it must satisfy the property : $L(ay_1(x) +by_2(x)) =aLy_1(x) +bLy_2(x)$. How can I show this is true if it's supposedly linear ?